# Visual Studio 2012 broken/buggy ASP.NET string termination detection

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

For an ASP.NET MVC3 project not (yet!) using the Razor syntax, is there any way to stop Visual Studio from displaying warnings in the error list and showing red intellisense errors on perfectly valid code in a View that looks like this:

```
<input type='image' src='/images/buy-now.png' 
   onclick='return DoAjaxRequest("<%= Model.Order.Invoice %>");' />
```

The `"` preceding the opening `<%=` and everything following the terminating `%>` appear with a red squiggle with hover text that says "Unterminated string constant."

This code obviously compiles and runs fine, but the warnings are a little annoying. I'd love to be able to refactor around them without moving to Razor?

I tried using an ugly `string.Format` workaround, but though it compiles fine, it too gives an intellisense error, this time for the entire contents of the `<%= %>` bit, complaining about "Expression expected"

```
<%= string.Format("<input type='image' src='/images/buy-now.png' 
   onclick='return DoAjaxRequest(\"{0}\");' />", Model.Order.Invoice); %>
```

Comment: I don't have the problem you're seeing in VS 2010.  I'm using ReSharper though, and that could be why.  Or, maybe you have some plug-in that is causing the problem.

Comment: I'm using VS2012 and ReSharper.

Comment: That is annoying, i'm seeing it in 2012 as well.  Doesn't happen in 2010.

Comment: In fact, it happens with Razor syntax as well! `onclick="return DoAjaxRequest('@Model.Invoice');" />`

Comment: See this all the time...

Answer (score 1):

Razor syntax error is now under the review feedback

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759398/razor-input-and-onclick

I believe they'll fixed even non-razor syntax.